# How can I put an image into my div?

Tags: html, css, image, src

I am trying to put an img at the bottom of my page that touches the left and right side of the screen.

HTML:

```
<div id="maincover">
<img src="http://imgur.com/a/vlURG"/>
</div>
```

Not sure what to have as CSS in order to make it happen

Comment: ..into your div?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
  #maincover img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#maincover {
    background-image:url(http://imgur.com/a/vlURG);
    background-position:bottom;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#maincover{width:100%;height:100px;position: absolute;bottom: 0;}
#maincover img{width:100%;height:100%;}
```

```html
<div id="maincover">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/rklSO2e.jpg"/>
</div>
```